# Dynamics AX 2009 Visual Studio Template Files

Tags: visual-studio, templates, dynamics-ax-2009

Where online can I download the Visual Studio template files for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009?
[alt text http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/8852/47201012000pm.png](http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/8852/47201012000pm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dynamics AX Web Project template is installed when you install the Enterprise Portal developer tools from the Dynamics AX 2009 installation media.

You can download Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 from [CustomerSource](http://www.microsoft.com/dynamics/en/us/customersource.aspx) if you are a licensed Dynamics customer, [PartnerSource](http://www.microsoft.com/dynamics/en/us/partner-login.aspx) if you are a Microsoft Partner, or [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/securedownloads/default.aspx) if you are a Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate subscriber.